# Windows phone 8 C++ Component Debugging - NO Symbols

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I created a Windows Phone 8 project from Microsofts XAML - Direct3d template in Visual Studio 2012.

When I place a breakpoint in the C#-Xaml project and start debugging, the debugger stops on the breakpoint with no problem.

However, if I place a breakpoint in the  C++-Direct3D component project, the breakpoint never gets hit and the debugger complains that there are no symbols loaded and the module browser says the Binary was not built with debug information.

I have triple checked the project settings for the C++ component, and debug symbols are indeed being built.

How can I get debugging and breakpoints in the C++ component working?

From the Module window in VS 2012:

```
PhoneDirect3DXamlAppComponent.winmd C:\Data\Programs\{0827E110-DAB9-49BB-A331-0A7FF54F418C}\Install\PhoneDirect3DXamlAppComponent.winmd No  N/A Binary was not built with debug information.        10      11/9/2012 12:29 PM  03640000-03642000   [2568] TaskHost.exe [1] Silverlight AppDomain
```

Comment: I figured it out. Go to the properties for the C#-XAML project and make sure you set UI Task and Agent Task, under Debugger Type, to "Native Only".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the fix for your problem, but anyway you should switch the debugger from "Managed Only" to "Native Only". You can do that in the properties screen of your *managed* project. (probably under "UI Task")